# Bernoulli equation for pressure (with the vortex)

Tags: mathematical-physics, fluid-dynamics

An incompressible inviscid fluid of constant density ρ moves subject to a gravitational acceleration −gk.
The vortex caused by water flowing down a plughole is modelled by the steady velocity ￼￼￼field

when $x^2+y^2\le a^2$

$$u=\left(\frac{Γy}{a^2},-\frac{Γx}{a^2},0 \right)  $$ 
when  $x^2+y^2\gt a^2$
$$\left(\frac{Γy}{x^2+y^2},-\frac{Γx}{x^2+y^2},0 \right)   $$
 Evaluate the pressure in such a flow.

need to show that when  $x^2+y^2\le a^2$

a free surface at a constant pressure takes the form of

$$C − \frac{Γ^2(2a^2-x^2-y^2)}{2ga^4} $$

and when $x^2+y^2\gt a^2$

a free surface takes the form of 
 $$C − \frac{Γ^2}{2g(x^2+y^2)} $$

I did work out the  $x^2+y^2\gt a^2$ one by using the Bernoulli's equation for irrotational flow but don't know the other one with vorticity since for steady irrotational flow $p+\frac{1}{2}\rho|\mathbf u|^2+\rho gz=constant$

But how to get the rotational part,should I also use the Bernoulli's equation? But it doesn't have the constant part then how should I approach it?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For inviscid, rotational flow a weaker form of the Bernoulli equation $p + \frac{1}{2} \rho | \mathbf{u}|^2 + \rho g z  = C(\psi)$ is valid, where $C(\psi)$ is constant along a streamline. You can work with this or solve for the pressure field directly from the governing equations for inviscid flow, which reveals the Bernoulli relationship as well.

Using  cylindrical coordinates we have $x = r \cos \theta, \, y = r \sin \theta,$ and the basis vectors

$$\mathbf{e}_r = \cos \theta \, \mathbf{e}_x + \sin \theta \, \mathbf{e}_y, \\\mathbf{e}_\theta = -\sin \theta \, \mathbf{e}_x + \cos \theta \, \mathbf{e}_y $$

The velocity field is,  for  $r^2 = x^2 + y^2 \leqslant a^2 $,

$$u_r = 0, \,\, u_\theta = - \frac{\Gamma r}{a^2}, \,\, u_z = 0,$$

and for $x^2 + y^2 > a^2$,

$$u_r = 0, \,\, u_\theta = - \frac{\Gamma }{r}, \,\, u_z = 0$$

The components of the Euler equation for steady, inviscid flow, $\rho\mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{u} \,\, = - \nabla p + \rho \mathbf{g}$, reduce to

$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial r} = \frac{\rho u_\theta^2}{r} = \begin{cases}\frac{\rho \Gamma^2r}{a^4}, \,\, x^2+y^2 \leqslant a^2 \\  \frac{\rho \Gamma^2}{r^3}, \,\,\,\, x^2+y^2 > a^2\end{cases}$$

and

$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial z}= -\rho g$$

Integrating, we get for $x^2 + y^2 \leqslant a^2$,

$$p = \alpha - \rho g z + \frac{\rho \Gamma^2 r^2}{2a^4}  = \alpha - \rho g z + \frac{\rho \Gamma^2 (x^2 + y^2)}{2a^4},$$

and, for $x^2 + y^2 > a^2$,

$$p = \beta - \rho g z - \frac{\rho \Gamma^2}{2r^2} =  \beta - \rho g z - \frac{\rho \Gamma^2}{2(x^2 + y^2)} $$

The integration constant $\alpha$  can be evaluated in terms of $\beta \,$ by matching the inner pressure field with the outer pressure field at $x^2 + y^2 = a$, where we have

$$\alpha - \rho g z + \frac{\rho \Gamma^2 (a^2)}{2a^4} = \beta - \rho g z - \frac{\rho \Gamma^2}{2a^2} $$

Solving for $\alpha$ we get

$$\alpha = \beta - \frac{\rho \Gamma^2}{a^2}, $$

and the inner pressure field is

$$p = \beta - \frac{\rho \Gamma^2}{a^2} - \rho g z + \frac{\rho \Gamma^2 (x^2 + y^2)}{2a^4}$$

The free-surface where $p = C$ is given by

$$z = \frac{\beta-C}{\rho g} - \frac{\Gamma^2}{g a^2} + \frac{ \Gamma^2 (x^2 + y^2)}{2ga^4}$$

Comment: Thank you so much! So the trick is for the rotational using the Euler equation,it needs to take the cylindrical coordinate. Then it needs to take the integral to make sure that the inner pressure and outer pressure at the boundary match (this is where the first non-constant term for x^2+y^2<=a^2 comes from?)

Comment: And your steps are the evaluation of the pressure and it only needs a little change( to take the z to the other side and set the pressure to be constant then we can get the free surface?)

Comment: Why for the rotational, we need to use the cylindrical coordinate

Comment: for the x^2+y^2<=a^2 do we still need the z term in the pressure equation?

Comment: Switching to cylindrical coordinates is not necessary it just  makes it easier to solve.  Yes $\rho g z$ belongs to both solutions. It just accounts for the hydrostatic pressure due to gravity.

Comment: Thank you so much! But can you show how to get from p to z (equation manipulation) because when I try to do it I get different sign of the equation I get z =C+Γ^2/a^2-Γ^2(x^2+y^2)/2a^4

Comment: I think about it. Should the pressure at the boundary with different sign?

Comment: I found my mistake.  Now our signs match.  I had gravity pointing in the positive z-direction originally, but changed it to your convention which is correct.

Comment: I have written out the complete detailed solution and thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help.